# python rosmsg/rospack in ROS2

Tags: ros, ros2, msg, rospkg, rclpy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have some python code using rosmsg and rospkg, i.e.

```
rospack = rospkg.RosPack()
lines = rosmsg.get_msg_text(msg_name, False, rospack)
```

how to do the same in ROS2 with rclpy?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/321062/python-rosmsg/rospack-in-ros2/) by [federico.ferri](https://answers.ros.org/users/3836/federico.ferri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2019-04-14

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here's what I do:

```
from rosidl_runtime_py import get_interface_path
from rosidl_adapter.parser import parse_message_file
m = parse_message_file('std_msgs', get_interface_path('std_msgs/msg/Bool'))
```

it's actually better than what you do with RosPack as `parse_message_file` parses the lines for you and returns a nice object with all the info in it.

---

Originally posted by [fferri](https://answers.ros.org/users/6966/fferri/) with karma: 46 on 2020-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1